# How to make a scrollable JTable

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

**Question 1)** I have a JPanel ps, which has a null layout; a JScrolPane scrollPane, and a JTable table.
I have added the table to the scrollPane, and then added the scrollPane to the Jpanel ps. The following is my code for doing that:-

```
ps = new JPanel();
ps.setLayout(null);
ps.setSize(1000,600);

scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
scrollPane.setBounds(10, 119, 975, 300);
        scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
ps.add(scrollPane);

table = new JTable(data, columns);
table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
```

It is supposed t create a scrollPane with horizontal scrollbars, and when the number of columns increases in such a way that, it cannot be handled on a single screen, the scrollbar helps to display the contents. See "AUTO_RESIZE_OFF".

But what happens is that, the the size of all the columns is fixed (I don't know how many characters. The width of all of them is same.). The name of the columns is thus not fully viewable.

My question is, is it possible to increase the width of the column shown, or to show all the columns with their own width ? Also, how to enable scrolling ?

Comment: Maybe I'm over thinking this but what do you mean by "print" the data in the table. Like to a file, a printer, console output...

Comment: I meant about printing the data in the table to an A# size paper.

Comment: -1 - You won't get good answers by asking 3 totally unrelated things in one Question.  And such Q&A's are unhelpful for other people.  Please read the FAQ and other advice on how to ask good questions.

Comment: sorry, i will break down the questions.

Comment: related or not: don't do any manual sizing/positioning (aka: null layout) **ever** - that's the exclusive task of a LayoutManager

Answer (score 4):

1. Yes. See [`TableColumn`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableColumn.html). Generally what I've done in the past is used the `ResultSetMeta` data to build the column model. Take a look at [How to use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#width) for more information
2. Yes, but `JTable` can be a little trouble some. Take a look at [Printing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/index.html) and [Printing a JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#printing). There are some great examples on SO if you have the time to look.
3. It's always better to filter the data at the database end. Once you have a set of results, of you wanted to filter that set, you could use its `ResultSetMetaData`  to determine which columns you want to group by. Equally, if you don't have results yet, you could use the `DatabaseMetaData` to determine the columns of the tables in the database

Answer (score 3):

1. Regarding to your print job in  question 1 & 2: I recommend you should have a look at [jasper report](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library)
2. For your question 3, I do not know what your database structure is, so it is hard to tell, but look like what you are looking for is row span in JTable. So, try to look around [google](https://www.google.com.vn/search?q=row%20span%20jtable%20&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a) for such thing